# Installation of package ‘rjags’ had non-zero exit status

Tags: r, jags

S.O.: Linux Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
R: R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18) -- "World-Famous Astronaut"
Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)

When I try to install the package `rjags`, I get the following fatal error:

```
install.packages("rjags")
Installing package into ‘/home/marco/.rkward/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
trying URL 'http://mirrors.softliste.de/cran/src/contrib/rjags_3-15.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 66879 bytes (65 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 65 KB

* installing *source* package ‘rjags’ ...
** package ‘rjags’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for prefix by checking for jags... no
configure: error: "Location of JAGS headers not defined. Use configure arg '--with-jags-include' or environment variable 'JAGS_INCLUDE'"
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rjags’
* removing ‘/home/marco/.rkward/library/rjags’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpditLat/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("rjags") :
  installation of package ‘rjags’ had non-zero exit status
```

Apparently, the first error message is

> configure: error: "Location of JAGS headers not defined. Use configure arg '--with-jags-include' or environment variable 'JAGS_INCLUDE'"

How can I solve this?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: You need `jags` (*Just Another Gibbs Sampler for Bayesian MCMC simulation*) to be installed in your system.On Ubuntu 14.04, `sudo apt-get install jags` should work.

Answer (score 5):

As a top comment explained, you need JAGS (Just Another Gibbs Sampler) to be installed in your system. Since you're using Ubuntu 14.04, running

```
sudo apt-get install jags
```

should be enough. However, in case you're in another distribution (or, for some reason, the code above doesn't work for you), it's a good idea to know how to get JAGS from the source:

1. Access http://mcmc-jags.sourceforge.net/
2. Look for the proper version under "Downloads". For instance, Fedora users should look into the Fedora_20 folder of http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/cornell_vrdc/
3. Don't forget to *download both the base as well as the devel versions*.

After the installation is successful, you can go back to R (which can stay open during the whole thing, anyway) and install the package you want.

Comment: +1. Might be worth noting - I built jags from source to a non-standard location (I don't have root access on my server), and had to use the following style to install `runjags` (I guess `rjags` would be similar): `install.packages("runjags", configure.args = c("--with-jags-include={path_to_jags}/include/JAGS", "--with-jags-lib={path_to_jags}/lib"))`

Answer (score 3):

To me, first, I worked with the installation jags by terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install jags
```

and then

```
install.packages("rjags")
```

And the error was gone.

Answer (score 1):

1) If necessary Download and install R (https://www.r-project.org/) and potentially a user interface to R like R Studio (see here for tips on getting started with R).
2) Download and install JAGS as per operating system requriements. (http://mcmc-jags.sourceforge.net/)
3) Install additional R packages: e.g., in R install.packages("rjags") . In particular, I use the packages rjags to interface with JAGS and coda to process MCMC output.